# Framerate issue FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I got a strange bug when I try to stream a m3u8 or .ts file with ffmpeg.

When I stream this line in ffmpeg:
`C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i "http://myurl.com/myfile.ts" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -vprofile main -vb 1000k -s 720x400 -aspect 16:9 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 64k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp://myurl.com/mystream"`

When I run this command the framerate is not standing on 30fps but getting a lot of times above 100 fps.

Like this

`frame=  107 fps=0.0 q=31.0 size=     469kB time=00:00:04.40 bitrate= 871.6kbits/<br>
frame=  186 fps=163 q=30.0 size=     873kB time=00:00:07.54 bitrate= 948.5kbits/<br>
frame=  246 fps=149 q=31.0 size=    1225kB time=00:00:09.97 bitrate=1006.1kbits/<br>
frame=  327 fps=152 q=31.0 size=    1647kB time=00:00:13.23 bitrate=1019.2kbits/<br>
frame=  425 fps=160 q=28.0 size=    1938kB time=00:00:17.07 bitrate= 929.5kbits/<br>
frame=  476 fps=151 q=28.0 size=    2261kB time=00:00:19.16 bitrate= 966.4kbits/<br>
frame=  527 fps=144 q=29.0 size=    2623kB time=00:00:21.21 bitrate=1012.9kbits/<br>
frame=  618 fps=148 q=28.0 size=    2989kB time=00:00:24.86 bitrate= 984.7kbits/<br>
frame=  688 fps=147 q=27.0 size=    3308kB time=00:00:27.63 bitrate= 980.6kbits/<br>
frame=  739 fps=143 q=29.0 size=    3726kB time=00:00:29.70 bitrate=1027.5kbits/<br>
frame=  770 fps= 49 q=30.0 size=    3974kB time=00:00:31.00 bitrate=1050.0kbits/<br>
frame=  849 fps= 53 q=30.0 size=    4464kB time=00:00:34.14 bitrate=1071.0kbits/<br>
frame=  944 fps= 57 q=29.0 size=    4834kB time=00:00:37.98 bitrate=1042.5kbits/<br>
frame= 1037 fps= 61 q=29.0 size=    5252kB time=00:00:41.56 bitrate=1035.0kbits/<br>
frame= 1104 fps= 63 q=29.0 size=    5689kB time=00:00:44.25 bitrate=1053.1kbits/<br>
frame= 1192 fps= 66 q=30.0 size=    6186kB time=00:00:47.81 bitrate=1059.8kbits/<br>`

Can someone help me with this bug. Now the output is really bad.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That's how many `fps` it encodes, not the frame-rate of the output. Your output is garbled because you're pumping it at the maximum speed.

Use the `-re` option for non-live input streams to read at the native frame rate and output in real-time:

`C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -re -i "http://myurl.com/myfile.ts" ...`

> **-re (input)**
>
> Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab device. or live input stream (e.g. when reading from a file).
>   Should not be used with actual grab devices or live input streams
>   (where it can cause packet loss). By default ffmpeg attempts to read
>   the input(s) as fast as possible. This option will slow down the
>   reading of the input(s) to the native frame rate of the input(s). It
>   is useful for real-time output (e.g. live streaming).

[Docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)